# Is it possible to get a list of IPEndPoints on a remote pc on my network using c#

Tags: c#, tcp, system.net

As the title suggests, I'd like to know if it's possible to get a list of System.Net.IPEndPoint on a remote server.

I know this can be done on a local machine using ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners as I've done it, but as far as I can tell, ipGlobalProperties is for the local machine only.

Instead of deploying our application to all of our servers, we'd like to centralise  it and have it monitor active listeners across out network for a given list of servers.

Comment: So, you want a port scan?

Comment: This could indeed be very handy in some scenarios, but I think it would be a potential security risk to have it in general.

Comment: To extend this further, we want to run some code that will check for ports on our network that have SSL certificates on them so we can interrogate them to ensure we keep them up to date. As some of these open ports arent just on 443, we want to check open ports and see if they're ssl, but have this be dynamic.